# Using React Hooks in in an IIFE breaks rules of hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-context

**Background**

I'm working on a sidebar component that can be opened from many buttons in the UI. I want to 1) only render it once, 2) grant access to update its `isVisible` state to these buttons without drilling props down through a common ancestor.

**Expectations vs Reality**

I'd expect that I could create a context with its own api method to update an internal state. In my code sample I'm attempting to do this with an IIFE.

**Questions**

1. How does this break the rules of hooks?
2. How else can I provide an update function to this context?

```
export const SidebarContext = createContext((() => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)

  return {
    isVisible,
    toggleVisibility: () => setIsVisible(!isVisible)
  }
})())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createContext()` receives the default value. So you're defining a function which is invoked immediately and the result of it will be used as default value for the context. That's where the `useState` breaks [this rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions):

> Call Hooks from React function components.

In order to accomplish what you want you can do this:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const SidebarContext = createContext();

function Provider({ children }) {

  let [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  let toggle = useCallback(() => setIsVisible(s => !s), [setIsVisible])

  // Pass the `state` and `functions` to the context value
  return (
    <SidebarContext.Provider value={{ isVisible, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </SidebarContext.Provider>
  );
}

function YourButton() {
  let { isVisible, toggle } = useContext(SidebarContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Sidebar is {isVisible : 'open': 'close'}</div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>
        Toggle
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <YourButton />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```